# All my desktop looks different today. How can I back to the old configuration?

Tags: desktop-environments

I use Ubuntu Studio 18.04.2 LTS.

Today, in one of my desktop PCs, I found my desktop looks totally different with my "classic" configuration.

[image]

I'm talking specifically about the kind of characters on the desktop icons (they weren't bold), and about the lower panel characters (they are white).

Also, the Mozilla Firefox text, in that panel,, wasn't with a light blue background.

My old desktop looks like this (this image is from my laptop)

[image]

I hope you can understand the changes. The background image is not the important thing. I'm talking about the icon characters and the panel characters.

How can I fix this?

How can I get back to me old configuration?

Comment: I think I found the solution. I used the line command: sudo grep " install " /var/log/dpkg.log to see which software had been installed in the last few days. I found some breeze and plasma theme and some KDE colors related software. Well, I uninstalled all those packages and... Now I have the looks I had before! I don't know if this is the final answer to this, but... It works for me!

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer below by clicking the 'Answer your question' button. It's absolutely fine (and very much encouraged) to [self-answer your question](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> I found the solution. I used the line command:
>
> ```
> sudo grep " install " /var/log/dpkg.log
> ```
>
> to see which software had been installed in the last few days. I found some breeze and plasma
>   theme and some KDE colors related software. Well, I uninstalled all
>   those packages. Now I have the looks I had before.
>   <sub>(from a [comment by OP](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1133560/all-my-desktop-looks-different-today-how-can-i-back-to-the-old-configuration#comment1878919_1133560))</sub>